# New-ModuleManifest does not prompt for standard keys

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.0

On Windows 10, using PowerShell 5.0.10586.494 the `New-ModuleManifest` cmdlet just returns after prompting for the file path. This goes against the documentation.

How to Write a Module Manifest

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878297(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you look at the bottom of that page, Thomas Lee commented in 2012 that as of v3.0 it only prompts for path.

Answer (score 0):

That's seemingly how it works these days. You just edit the created manifest by hand thereafter.